# How do I get the value from a variable which has it's values assigned in another class?

Tags: c#

I need to have a class for `Variables` and `Methods` for the sake of *manageability*.
The problem is I am not sure how I can access the value of the variable assigned in the method class.

Here is the variable class, it just holds variables:

```
namespace Classes
{
    class MyVariableClass
    {
        public string MyVariable { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Here is the method:*
I am calling an instance of the variable class in the method class so that I can assign the variable to the values of the method.

```
namespace Classes
{
    class MyMethods
    {
        MyVariableClass myVarClass = new MyVariableClass();

        public void DoSomeStuff(string myString1, string myString2)
        {
           myVarClass.MyVariable = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString2)
               ? myString2 : "String 2 has nothing!");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, below is the Main Method:
When I run this code, MyVariable returns null, I am assuming I am accessing the variable before it is assigned it's values?

How do I get the variable with the values assigned in the Method class?

```
namespace Classes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           MyMethods myMethod = new MyMethods();
           MyVariableClass myVarClass = new MyVariableClass();

            string something = "something";
            string nothingHere = null;

            myMethod.DoSomeStuff(something, nothingHere);

            //I need to call MyVariable here
            //Or be able to access it's values assigned in the MyMethod Class.

            Console.Write(myVarClass.MyVariable);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable `myVarClass` in method `Main` and field `myVarClass` of `MyMethods` class are different objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** You are working on two different objects.

1. you are creating an object with an instance variable `myVarClass` in `MyMethods` class.
2. you are creating one more new object with an instance variable `myVarClass`  in Main() method.

**Note :** You should always remeber that in object oriented programming  objects are independent and maintain their own copy so modifying one object parameters/properties doesnot effect the other object parameters or properties.

**Solution :** instead of creating two different object create only one object with instance variable `myVarClass`  in `Main()` method and pass it to the `myClass` method.

so you should change your `myClass`  method `DoSomeStuff()` as below to accept the instance variable of `MyVariableClass``

```
 public void DoSomeStuff(MyVariableClass myVarClass, string myString1, string myString2)
 {
   //do something
 }
```

from `Main()` method call the above method as below:

```
MyVariableClass myVarClass = new MyVariableClass();    
string something = "something";
string nothingHere = null;    
myMethod.DoSomeStuff(myVarClass, something, nothingHere);
```

**Complete Code:**

```
namespace Classes
{
    class MyMethods
    {              
        public void DoSomeStuff(MyVariableClass myVarClass, string myString1, string myString2)
        {
           myVarClass.MyVariable = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString2)
               ? myString2 : "String 2 has nothing!");
        }
    }
}
```

and Main Program should be :

```
namespace Classes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           MyMethods myMethod = new MyMethods();
           MyVariableClass myVarClass = new MyVariableClass();

            string something = "something";
            string nothingHere = null;

            myMethod.DoSomeStuff(myVarClass, something, nothingHere);

            //I need to call MyVariable here
            //Or be able to access it's values assigned in the MyMethod Class.

            Console.Write(myVarClass.MyVariable);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `an instance variable myVarClass in Main() method` it is local variable.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: i diddn't get you , could you please elaborate it?

Comment: Thanks my friends: These are all very great and interesting solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The `myVarClass` member of `MyMethods` is private by default, so if you want to be able to call it from outside the class itself, then you need to make it `public`.

Once public, you'll able to do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   MyMethods myMethod = new MyMethods();
   MyVariableClass myVarClass = new MyVariableClass();

    string something = "something";
    string nothingHere = null;

    myMethod.DoSomeStuff(something, nothingHere);

    //I need to call MyVariable here
    //Or be able to access it's values assigned in the MyMethod Class.

    Console.Write(myMethod.myVarClass.MyVariable);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Also, be careful with the fact that the `myVarClass` defined in `main` is a completely different object.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Define you class as:

```
namespace Classes
{
    class MyMethods
    {
        public MyVariableClass MyVarClass {get; private set;}


        public void DoSomeStuff(string myString1, string myString2)
        {
           if(MyVarClass == null)
           {
              MyVarClass = new MyVariableClass();
           }

           MyVarClass.MyVariable = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString2)
               ? myString2 : "String 2 has nothing!");
        }
    }
}
```

then use as:

```
namespace Classes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           MyMethods myMethod = new MyMethods();

            string something = "something";
            string nothingHere = null;

            myMethod.DoSomeStuff(something, nothingHere);

            //I need to call MyVariable here
            //Or be able to access it's values assigned in the MyMethod Class.

            Console.Write(myMethod.MyVarClass.MyVariable);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the need for the Conditional Statement when instantiating the class in the Method above? Just trying to understand your approach.

            `if(MyVarClass == null)
           {
              MyVarClass = new MyVariableClass();
           }`

Comment: Lazy initialization. You can avoid this construction and initialize it in constructor or in declaration.